# Minha API Node JS, que utiliza um child process, funciona quando executada pelo nodemon, cmd mas no PM2 gera erro

Tags: python, node.js

Minha API executa um script python através de uma rota do Express, utilizando child process, eu já tentei rodar apenas o script utilizando python nomeDoScript e funcionou, não sei por quê está dando esse erro de Python ENOENT.
Parte do código em Node JS:

```
    app.post('/python', chamandoPython)

    async function chamandoPython(req, res) {
      var process = spawn('python', ["./PythonServices/main.py", 
       "./uploads/"]).on('error', function( err ){ throw err })
      process.stdout.on('data', async function (data) {
        await res.send(data.toString())
      })
      process.stderr.on('data', async function (data) {
        console.log("stderr" + data.toString())
      })
     }
```

Quando eu executo esse arquivo pelo nodemon, funciona perfeitamente, mas quando "starto" ele pelo PM2, retorna esse erro:

```
    $Error: spawn python ENOENT
    $  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:268:19)
    $  at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:470:16)
    $  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
    $errno: 'ENOENT',
    $code: 'ENOENT',
    $syscall: 'spawn python',
    $path: 'python',
    $spawnargs: [ './PythonServices/main.py', './uploads/' ]
    $}
```

Eu estou tentando colocar minha API em um servidor, o código na minha máquina funciona tanto pelo nodemon/node como no PM2 porém, no servidor, funciona apenas quando executado no nodemon/node. O mesmo código gera esse erro apenas quando executado no PM2.

Comment: Geralmente este erro é relacionado à quando o arquivo não pode ser encontrado. A única coisa que pode explicar este comportamento é permissões de execução/visualização dos arquivos, no filesystem, poderia dar uma procurada via o ls -la para verificar permissões vs execução do pm2 e node.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou procurar saber mais sobre o filesystem e sobre esse ls, se tiver algum documento que possa me passar ficarei ainda mais agradecido. Obrigado novamente!

Comment: Este `"./PythonServices/main.py"` está usando caminho relativo. Use `"/caminho/completo/para/seu/script/PythonServices/main.py"`. Onde `/caminho/completo/para/seu/script/` são os diretórios desde o raiz até o script. Ficou confuso, mas espero que entenda.

Comment: O erro não está relacionado ao diretório, o python que não está sendo reconhecido quando eu executo a API pelo pm2. Já testei com caminho relativo e completo e continuei com o mesmo erro.